# is it possible to use one mysql query to achieve this?

Tags: php, mysql

I am hoping for some help making my queries more efficient if possible. I have two tables. One which contains the types of content available and another which contains content linked to the type table by a type id.

I am trying to select from the content table and group the results by type_id. I am currently using a query inside a loop to do this so it is selecting again from the second table for each type_id. Is there a better/more efficient way to do this?

Here are my current tables and queries:

```
type_id     type
  1        type 1
  2        type 2

id    title   type_id    content 
1      test1    1      test content 1
2      test2    2      test content 2
3      test3    1      test content 3



$query="select type_id, type from type_table";

foreach($query as $type){

$query="select title, content from content_table WHERE type_id=$type['type_id']";
}
```

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: I think it's fairly important to know how you need to process the results of each type_id query in order to get good replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example appears to select *all* possible values from the content table, albeit in batches of a given type at a time. So `select title, content from content_table` would surely do this whole thing in one go, without looping.

To put each type_id into a new div, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT title, content, t.type_id, t.type
FROM content_table c
JOIN type_table t ON t.type_id = c.type_id
ORDER BY t.type_id

// pseudo-code
prev_type_id = -1
print "<div>"
foreach row:
    if type_id != prev_type_id:
        prev_type_id = type_id
        print "</div><div>"
print "</div>"
```

(edited based on comments)

Comment: Except that a) his batches are sorted, which your query isn't, and inside the loop, he has the information about the current type (because he's asked for it), which is missing from the data returned from your query.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I am not sure i explained myself correctly....

The reason I was using a foreach with the first table is because the results from the second query are going to displayed in separate divs created by the loop.

So each row of content will be grouped by type_id and displayed in a div with all other rows of the same type

Comment: @etarion well, not fully "sorted", but not completely intermixed like mine. But we know nothing about what happens inside the foreach loop; for all we know it could have been the previous developer's attempt to emulate a JOIN for not knowing a better way... (edited my answer now to take that into account)

Answer (score 0):

Use a join and order by. Something like (no guarantee for syntactical correctness):

```
SELECT 
    c.title, c.content, t.type_id, t.type 
FROM 
    type_table t, content_table c 
WHERE 
    c.type_id = t.type_id 
ORDER BY 
    t.type_id
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I am not sure i explained myself correctly....

The reason I was using a foreach with the first table is because the results from the second query are going to displayed in separate divs created by the loop.

So each row of content will be grouped by type_id and displayed in a div with all other rows of the same type

Comment: @Paul you can do that with this answer if you're happy to do some extra bookkeeping - like keeping track of the previous type_id and issuing a new div whenever it changes. Should be faster than running lots of queries, but does require a bit of extra coding.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could join the two tables.

In this example, however, it doesn't appear that you even need to use the type_table. You could just sort your query by type_id:

```
select title, content from content_table order by type_id;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I am not sure i explained myself correctly....

The reason I was using a foreach with the first table is because the results from the second query are going to displayed in separate divs created by the loop.

So each row of content will be grouped by type_id and displayed in a div with all other rows of the same type

Answer (score 0):

What is the expected result ?

This is what I think you want.

```
$sql = 'SELECT t.type, c.title, c.content
        FROM `content_table` c
        INNER JOIN `type_table` t ON c.type_id = t.type_id
        ORDER BY c.type_id ASC'

// Dont use a foreach-loop to loop over the results. While-loop is ideal
while ($row = <query or fetch from resultset here>) {
 ..
}
```